# blacken screen in iOS while app is running

Tags: ios, ipad

I want my iPad app to completely blacken the screen but retain all the standard functionality.

I'm doing this to test the non-visual aspects of the app (to test what the app would be like if you were a blind user).

Is this possible?

Comment: Have you considered closing your eyes?

Comment: There are very advanced tools for this kind of test too. For example this one: http://i44.tinypic.com/28auw4p.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen Apple's testing guide for accessibly?

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/iPhoneAccessibility/Testing_Accessibility/Testing_Accessibility.html

Blind users make use of the phone through an accessibility mode which is quite different and takes care of blanking the screen for you.

[Article](http://mattgemmell.com/2010/12/19/accessibility-for-iphone-and-ipad-apps/) by Matt Gemmell on accessibility.

Comment: yeah i'm definitely aware of the iOS built in voice over. i'm building my own accessibility settings into the app natively so i'd like a easy way to test it with sighted users who don't want to wear a blindfold

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

http://vectorvector.tumblr.com/post/2130331861/ignore-touches-to-uiview-subclass-but-not-to-its

Basically I create a black view on top of my application and then have that view pass touches to subviews.